# streamlit use st.cache_data at test.py initialization

Tags: streamlit

I am trying to create a website with Streamlit, and I am having trouble with removing warning messages when my .py file is initialized. I found that this arises from the following module:

```
st.image_select
```

4 images from the local folder are selected to be displayed. The code for this is:

```
# configs
work_path = 'C:/Users/me/Desktop/webpage'
IMG_SIZE = 512
image1 = load_dicom(f"{work_path}/images/1.2.826.0.1.3680043.1363_120.dcm")
image2 = load_dicom(f"{work_path}/images/1.2.826.0.1.3680043.4202_134.dcm")
image3 = load_dicom(f"{work_path}/images/1.2.826.0.1.3680043.30067_108.dcm")
image4 = load_dicom(f"{work_path}/images/1.2.826.0.1.3680043.26979_144.dcm")

# display images; this is where the message comes from
img = image_select(
    label="Select a patient",
    images=[image1, image2, image3, image4,],
    captions=[
        "1.2.826.0.1.3680043.1363",
        "1.2.826.0.1.3680043.4202",
        "1.2.826.0.1.3680043.30067",
        "1.2.826.0.1.3680043.26979"
    ],
)
```

I followed the official github page: https://github.com/jrieke/streamlit-image-select

Although I could get image boxes successfully, when I run this, I am keep getting the message box, telling that I have to use 'st.cache_data' instead of 'st.experimental_memo'. I have not used any st.experimental_memo, nor need it.

[screenshot of the webpage demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mABI.png)

But when I refresh the page, the two boxes disappear. What I want to do is to remove the boxes even when initialized. I am hoping if I can get any suggestions or advices on this. Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

You were seeing that error because `st.experimental_memo` was deprecated and the source code for `streamlit-image-select` had not been updated. It has since been [updated](https://github.com/jrieke/streamlit-image-select) and you can try again.

[image]